# Excel formula that returns specific lists of values?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Help is appreciated!

I have two columns of data. The first is a participant ID column. The second adjacent column are the binary coded respective responses (example below). I am interested in all of the 1's.

Does anyone know a formula which can extract a list of all of the participants who have scored a 1?

E.g., (**Particpant ID is value on the left**, *and the participants' score is to the right*).

**1** *0*

**2** *1*

**3** *1*

**4** *0*

**5** *0*

**6** *1*

Comment: You would get such a list by applying a filter. Then, to extract it to another location you would need to copy and paste the visible cells.

Comment: Hey Variatus, thank you for this. Do you know if there is a way that I can keep the participant ID WITH the respective 1value? I want to be able to keep each detected 1 value, with the respective ID. Sorry, I should have clarified that in my question.

Comment: Hold on, your suggestion has worked, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FILTER()` formula will do that. Try-

```
=FILTER(A2:A7,B2:B7=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your helpful response Harun24HR! :)

Comment: @JuliaGillett Glad to know!